# Joomla 1.6 and CakePHP integration

Tags: php, cakephp, joomla, joomla1.6

I dont seem to understand how do you integrate CakePHP framework with Joomla 1.6 CMS?

I have been reading and JAKE is commonly mentioned for the integration.

How does Jake assist in the integration, there are very limited resources online which guide me on this.

Is there any site where I can get a good understanding on the linkage between CakePHP with Joomla 1.6 using JAKE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max (the guy who made Jake) wrote an article back in 2007 explaining exactly how the linkage between Cake and Joomla works:

http://www.gigapromoters.com/blog/2007/01/28/joining-powers-of-two-great-systems-joomla-and-cakephp/

However, the official Jake site seems to be down and there has been very little talk of anything relating to Cake/Joomla since 2007.

Since then, however, there have been several CMSes created specifically for Cake, so perhaps one of those ones will do what you're looking for? Here's a good blog article with a mini-review of 13 different CakePHP CMSes:

http://blog.dreamcss.com/content-management-system/cakephp-based-cms/

Answer (score 1):

The Jake project was a great idea, but as you note it wasn't maintained for some time and the last release in 2007 is incompatible with the current stable versions of CakePHP and Joomla.

That in mind, I went ahead and upgraded it to work with the current CakePHP and Joomla, after adding in a feature to support friendlier URLs.  Feel free to check it out at http://blog.echothis.com/2012/09/26/jake-2-0-released/.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CakePHP component for Joomla 3 :

https://github.com/ahmad24/JCake

you can access the controller and action by passing the parameter `tasks=controllername.actionname`

Back end example:

```
localhost/joomla_32/administrator/index.php?option=com_jcake&tasks=tests.index
```

Front end example:

```
localhost/joomla_32/index.php?option=com_jcake&tasks=tests.index
```